# Byte manipulation of string array

Tags: c#, php

This question is a follow up to this previous question that I solved:

[manipulating bytes in a binary string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25717482/manipulating-bytes-in-a-binary-string)

In that question I explained that I have a working encryption communication between php and c#. I added a slight byte tweak to increase the obscurity level just a bit more. I have noticed however that about 1 in 50 times it fails to understand the encrypted content. This leads me to believe that my byte change- and byte revert code is not accounting for some edge case.

Note that I tested this with the same message over and over so the only thing that is changing is the IV which is randomized each time and appended in front of the encrypted data.

Here is what I am doing on the PHP side which encrypts the response. The idea is to roll the character over by 5, accounting for the limitations of base64

```
$data = getEncryptedBase64Data();
$ordVal = ord($data[strlen($data)-5]);
if($ordVal == 65)//'A'
{
    $ordVal = 47;//'/'
}
else if($ordVal == 48)//'0'
{
    $ordVal = 122;//'z'
}
else if($ordVal == 47)//'/'
{
    $ordVal = 45;//'+'
}
else if($ordVal == 45) //'+'
{
    $ordVal = 57;//'9'
}
else //B through z and 1 through 9
{
    $ordVal--;
}
$data[strlen($data)-5] = chr($ordVal);
return $data;
```

And here is what I am doing on the C# side which decrypts the response after it gets a Base64 string from the http response

```
string webText = //The content from the http response
byte[] decoded = Utils.FromBase64ServerString(webText);
//do decryption
```

where FromBase64ServerString is defined as

```
//Roll the 5th last bit to make things harder to decrypt
    char[] chars = s.ToCharArray();
    char ordinal = chars[chars.Length - 5];
    if(ordinal == 'z')
    {
        ordinal = '0';
    }
    else if(ordinal == '+')
    {
        ordinal = '/';
    }
    else if(ordinal == '/')
    {
        ordinal = 'A';
    }
    else if(ordinal == '9')
    {
        ordinal = '+';
    }
    else
    {
        ordinal++;
    }
    chars[chars.Length - 5] = ordinal;
    return Convert.FromBase64CharArray(chars,0,chars.Length);
```

Summary 
- Encryption code works fine on its own
- Adding a byte inc\dec after encryption and before decryption to reverse it only causes problems 5% of the time or so.
- Removing the byte fiddling and letting it spam messages back and forth all day results in no errors.

Comment: This does not help you fix your problem, but Base64 is not encryption - it's encoding. Encryption converts data so that only those who know the secret can decrypt and view it. Encoding is converting data to another form so that it can be transferred without error. I hope you're not sending sensitive data __encoded__ using base64.

Comment: As mentioned above, I my final data is the IV + encrypted data base 64 encoded ;)

Comment: the only values you encrypt are A-Z, a-z, 0-9, '+' and '/'? Or are you dealing with entire ASCII table?

Comment: Its base64 encoded values that im fiddling so the entire ascii table is not applicable in this situation.

Comment: Even if you get this working, it's really not adding anything significant. Either your encryption is adding enough security, or it's not. Adding a tiny bit of obscurity really isn't going to help.

Comment: I disagree. Somebody who knows enough about debugging to track usage of a common library, like the crypto ones, could potentially step through the code and grab the encryption key. That same person may not know nearly enough to figure out why thats not enough to make it work. Sure people out there exist who can easily solve this problem but it cuts down the pool of potential people by a lot in my mind.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the problem occurs because `else if($ordVal == 45)` in PHP code, the correct [ASCII](http://www.asciitable.com/) value for `+` is **43** not 45 (45 is `-` character) which cause the C# side to decode the string incorrectly. changing PHP code to following snippet should solve the problem.

```
$data = getEncryptedBase64Data();
$ordVal = ord($data[strlen($data)-5]);
if($ordVal == 65)//'A'
{
    $ordVal = 47;//'/'
}
else if($ordVal == 48)//'0'
{
    $ordVal = 122;//'z'
}
else if($ordVal == 47)//'/'
{
    $ordVal = 43;//'+'
}
else if($ordVal == 43) //'+'
{
    $ordVal = 57;//'9'
}
else //B through z and 1 through 9
{
    $ordVal--;
}
$data[strlen($data)-5] = chr($ordVal);
return $data;
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I can't believe i overlooked that. I was looking way to deep for a problem that was very high level ;)

Answer (score 0):

I think that you must be getting collisions.  If the ordinal-- produces one of your special chars then you will not reverse if correctly.

Comment: Turns out the guy above was correct, thanks for the input though.